# Cookieless Google Analytics v4 still generates _ga cookie

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I am trying to use the cookie-less Google Analytics implementation, so that our website can track visits before users accept cookies (switching to the standard version once they do), as per the Google Analytics documentation.

I'm using the technique described in this tutorial:
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-google-tag-manager-and-google-analytics-without-cookies-7d041c73cc76

I use the following code (simplified and stripped of irrelevant other scripts for the purpose of this post)

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'G-xxxxxxxx', {
    send_page_view: true,
    client_storage: 'none',
    client_id: '<key-from-local-storage>',
});
```

Everything seems to work using this method - until I look into the site cookies in inspector.
Regardless of the client_storage settings, a "_ga" cookie still gets generated.

When I use the standard cookie version of analytics (without the client_storage: "none") the same cookie gets generated, in exactly the same way.

I have also tried to use the Consent Mode for this, using the following code

```
gtag('consent', 'default', {
    analytics_storage: 'denied',
    ad_storage: 'denied'
});
```

later updating it to granted when user complies. This works in regards to blocking stuff, but also blocks ALL tracking from hapenning on Analytics - no results show up.

**Does anybody know of any way to actually get the Analytics to NOT generate the _ga cookie, but still track visited URLs and basic data, that does not require cookies?**

What does the cookie-less mode even do, when it generates the cookies just as before?

**Am I missing something?**

---

Edit:
I have tried using the same cookieless update on the older Analytics version, that uses ga(...) functions, and the cookie disappeared as expected. So it seems only the v4 is not working as intended.

Code used (that works):

```
ga('create',    'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', {
    'storage': 'none',
    'clientId': window.localStorage.getItem(GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
});
ga('send',      'pageview');
```

Comment: Have you found out what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into this for a while, it turns out that Google Analytics 4 doesn't follow the `client_storage: "none"` configuration mode.

This will work:

```js
// ✅ Configuring Universal Analytics (GA3) cookieless
gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-1', { client_storage: 'none' })
```

This won't work:

```js
// ❌ Trying to configure GA4 cookieless
gtag('config', 'G-123456789', { client_storage: 'none' })
```

I don't know if it's a bug or intentional, I couldn't find anything about it on [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=client_storage).

### How to fix it?

First, we tried using the [consent mode](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/consent) (i.e. `gtag("consent", "default", { analytics_storage: "denied"})`. But that wasn't an option for us, as using the consent mode will make your data not fully available in reports. In fact, data is modeled through a machine learning process [as explained here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11161109).

Instead, we tried to understand why GA4 is failing to send events to Google Analytics. Turns out, `gtag.js` can't send events due to the following error: "Unable to set cookie."

Our application doesn't use cookie at all (neither third-party tools), so we decided to override `document.cookie` and that worked. Here's our current configuration in production:

```js
// Override document.cookie
const cookies = {}

Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {
  get: function() {
    const allCookies = []
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(cookies)) {
      allCookies.push(`${key}=${value}`)
    }

    return allCookies.join('; ')
  },
  set: function(value) {
    const cookieParts = value.split('=')
    const cookieName = cookieParts.shift()
    const cookieValue = cookieParts.join('=')

    cookies[cookieName] = cookieValue
    return value
  }
})

// Initialize Google Analytics
function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments) }

gtag('js', new Date())
gtag('config', 'G-123456789')
```

This won't work for everybody as overriding `document.cookie` is clearly not recommended and can lead to unexpected situation. But that's the only thing that worked for us when migrating to GA4.

Comment: Thanks for sharing with us. It's a complete mess to get it working. I somehow got it working after all, but honestly I don't even know how... it seems that, paired with Google Tag Manager, with the "storage" turned off, it somehow works, but it's more magic than science at this point.

Also, isn't your code missing all the semicolons at the end of lines?

Comment: You're right. My linter is removing the semicolons automatically...